# Adobe Animate Actionscript 3.0 "clicktogotonextscene" code not working

Tags: actionscript-3, button

So I have the following code for a button called "n2" and as you can see it's supposed to take me to the next scene when I click it, but it isn't working. It is inside Scene 2 and I'm trying to get to the next one and whenever I test the scene and click it, I don't even get an error, it just doesn't work.
Btw, it's a GIF defined as a movie clip and then as a button. Could that be causing the problem?

```
 n2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextScene);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a trace in the function and comment out "MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();" you could then see if the function gets called on a button click.

I've not used animate before, but in flash you have to name your button/movieclip and then also name the instance. This allows you to create the object twice with two seperate names to be referred to by actionscript.

Not sure if this helps but thought I'd give you some things to try, good luck